# C++ postfix evaluation with decimal points

Tags: c++, evaluation, postfix-notation

I've got the shunting yard algorithm implemented (using code from wikipedia, modified to use stl stacks/queues), but now I'm wondering how it's going to evaluate decimals that I get from division. The javascript app at scriptasylum.com (can't link) works just fine and gives the expected output:

```
Infix: 1/6*((1/4)/(1/2)+1/2)
Postfix: 16/14/12//12/+*
Eval: 0.16666666666666666 (1/6)

Infix: 0.5+1
Postfix: 0.51+
Eval: 1.5
```

I found one example of postfix evaluation on here, but it wasn't finished and didn't account for decimal points.

Here's my current code: http://codepad.org/zDXnOELK

Comment: "Works just fine" ? Wouldn't it give `0.1667` then?

Comment: That was my rounding, not the app's. It's value was 0.16666666666666666.

Answer (score 2):

The easy thing (which is what the Javascript impl is doing, by virtue of the language semantics) is to represent *all* numbers internally as `double`.

If you want to do something cleverer, I gotta warn you that it's a *lot* more code and a *lot* more hard design decisions, and I recommend you start by reading up on the [Scheme numeric tower](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-reports/r5rs-html/r5rs_8.html#SEC50).

Comment: How does it tell the difference between 10.51+0.5 and 10.5+10.5? Both evaluate to 10.510.5+

Comment: You should be emitting a space after each token, otherwise yes, it's ambiguous.  (In other words, evaluate `10.51+0.5` to `10.51 0.5 +` and `10.5+10.5` to `10.5 10.5 +`.)  Also, I can't find the thing you're comparing against, but it may be directly evaluating the parse tree rather than serializing to postfix first.

Comment: s00pcan: Your problem has nothing to do with decimals and everything to do with having more than one digit in an operand.

Comment: I realize that. What can I do about it? Should I switch this stack to use strings or doubles instead of single chars, then read up until the next operator and then push it to the stack?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds about right.  (Operator or whitespace.)  `strtod` is your friend.

Comment: Modified the code to use a stack of strings for now. Not sure if that's what I want yet. But it makes it easier to have the operators in there with the numbers. infix:    1.0/60
postfix:    1.0 60 /

Comment: Ultimately you may want `stack<Term>` where `Term` is a class that can represent either an operator code or an operand.

Comment: Right now I have it basically working with operators over one digit and with decimal points. It gets tripped up by the parenthesis, but I'm going to work on that some more.